# Why is training accuracy at 99% but the prediction accuracy at 81% on the same data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I looked up similar questions to the problem but I dont understand still why it gives a such a result. Is it normal for a model to train up to 99% accuracy, but when used to predict on the same exact data, it gives a lower accuracy, in this case, 81%? Shouldn't it return back 99% accuracy?

Furthermore, when I present new unseen data, the prediction accuracy is an abysmal 17%. Surely this cannot be right. I understand that the model when presented new data should be less than the model's accuracy, but no way as bad as 17%.

Here is the code for context. I put comments for easier reading:

```
# Step 1) Split Data into Training and Prediction Sets
num_split_df_at = int(0.75*len(df))
np_train_data = df.iloc[0:num_split_df_at, columns_index_list].to_numpy()
np_train_target = list(df.iloc[0:num_split_df_at, 4])
np_predict_data = df.iloc[num_split_df_at:len(df), columns_index_list].to_numpy()
np_predict_target = list(df.iloc[num_split_df_at:len(df), 4])

# Step 2) Split Training Data into Training and Validation Sets
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np_train_data, np_train_target, random_state=0)


# Step 3) Reshape Training and Validation Sets to (49, 5)
# prints: "(3809, 245)"
print(x_train.shape)
# prints: "(1270, 245)"
print(x_test.shape)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], round(x_train.shape[1]/5), 5)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], round(x_test.shape[1]/5), 5)
y_train = np.array(y_train)- 1
y_test = np.array(y_test)- 1
# prints: "(3809, 49, 5)"
print(x_train.shape)
# prints: "[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]"
print(np.unique(y_train))
# prints: "10"
print(len(np.unique(y_train)))

input_shape = (x_train.shape[1], 5)

# Step 4) Run Model
adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(512, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv1D(512, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(512, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(512, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=150, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
print(model.summary())
model.save('model_1')

# Step 5) Predict on Exact Same Trained Data - Should Return High Accuracy
np_train_data = np_train_data.reshape(np_train_data.shape[0], round(np_train_data.shape[1]/5), 5)
np_train_target = np.array(np_train_target)- 1
predict_results = model.predict_classes(np_train_data)
print(accuracy_score(predict_results, np_train_target))

# Step 6) Predict on Validation Set
np_predict_data = np_predict_data.reshape(np_predict_data.shape[0], round(np_predict_data.shape[1]/5), 5)
np_predict_target = np.array(np_predict_target)- 1
predict_results = model.predict_classes(np_predict_data)
print(accuracy_score(predict_results, np_predict_target))
```

Here are the prediction results:

[image]

My input data looks similar to this - 49 Days, 5 data points per each day:
[image]

My output possible classification results are:

***[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]*** converted to ***[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]*** for "sparse_categorical_crossentropy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because the training accuracy/loss of Keras models are calculated batch wise and then averaged ([see here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10426#issuecomment-397485072)). instead the validation metrics/performance are computed simultaneously on all the data passed.

this is simply to verify in this dummy example. we train a NN and pass as valid data the same train data. in this way, we can compare (a) training acc, (b) validation acc, and (c) accuracy_score at the end of the train. as we can see (b) = (c) but (a) is different from (c) and (b) for the reason expressed above

```
timestamp, features, n_sample = 45, 2, 1000
n_class = 10
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, timestamp, features))
y = np.random.randint(0,n_class, n_sample)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(timestamp, features)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(8, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_class, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=5, validation_data=(X, y))

history.history['accuracy'][-1] # (a)
history.history['val_accuracy'][-1] # (b)
accuracy_score(y, np.argmax(model.predict(X), axis=1)) # (c)
```

Comment: As for the new data at 17%, is there a reason why it is so abysmal? is the model so overfitted that it produce such bad results?

Comment: The reason of the difference is presented in my answer. 99 vs 81 on the SAME TRAIN data is not the definition of overfitting... you are in overfitting when train acc is bigger (in huge terms) than val/test acc

Comment: @the_begging_beginner let me know if there are problems

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I appreciate it. I am still trying to digest what you wrote.
If I understand correctly (for the train acc vs vali acc), in my particular case, in the results image - where the accuracy is 0.9814 vs val_accuracy at 0.2774; thats the definition of overfitting no? If so, at what point (i.e. the difference between vali_acc and train_acc) is it no longer considered overfitted?

Comment: right 0.98 vs 0.27 is the correct way to 'evaluate' overfitting. In your case, u are in overfitting. this is difficult to define numerically, but a difference between acc of around 0.6 points is huge. there are lot of resources online about the topics and the technique to prevent it. Don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)